# Escape Dollar sign ($) in Jenkins emails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

In the content field of "Editable Email Notification" (Email-ext plugin in Jenkins) I would like to escape the $ sign so I can email "$WORD" which is an environment variable of the job (defined using Build Environment->Properties Content) without it being expanded to anything.
Backslashes doesn't seem to do...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To escape the $, just put another $ in front of it, e.g., $$WORD.

Answer (score 2):

If you have HTML body, to literally print a dollar sign `$` try `&dollar;` or `&#36;`

Comment: I tried both, but the emails i then get actually contains `&dollar;` (or `&#36;`). Or did you means to also add the ` signs?

Comment: No, no `\`` signs, but I assumed you had HTML email body, my mistake